# What should I consider when buying a (gaming) monitor?

Tags: monitors, gaming

I'm looking for a good, second 24" monitor.
What **specifications** do I have to look for in general when buying monitors?

I know, because it's my second 24" monitor, that it should fit well next to the existing one (same height, as small border as possible). But what else do I have to consider?

When buying my first monitor all I looked for was the right size and a good price. I ordered it online and therefore haven't seen it in person before. Would it be better to first look at a monitor in a shop before buying it?

I guess the specifications depend on the intended usage.
I'll use it mostly for gaming (I'll use the *better* one as my main monitor) and surfing. If the types of games also matter: Mostly FPS, GTA V and some rather old strategy games such as Anno 1503 or C&C Red Alert 2.

Comment: Do you care if it's different than your current one? For me, that'd be the factor to influence my decision the most. I couldn't handle two different monitors next to each other...

Comment: @enderland No, I totally don't. I already got a 21" next to my 24" one. I had to get used to it, but I'm totally okay with it. Like stated in my question I would just like it to be pretty much at the same height.
Actually, I don't want your answers to focus too much on the fact that it'll be a second monitor. I'm just wondering what specs one has to look for and thus, what I've possibly done wrong when buying the first one.

Comment: I've closed this question because it's more of a general advice-type question, which [are no longer in scope](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/343/do-we-still-want‌​-general-advice-questions/345#345).

Answer (score 10):

If you are planning to use it mainly for FPS gaming, and you are competitive in it, you are going to want to have a monitor that is 60hz - 144hz with a low response time <5ms.  The 60hz - 144hz is your refresh rate and it won't matter what graphics card you have if you have a monitor that is only running at 30hz.

If you're not on the competitive side then here are the different questions to answer to help you decide on what you want.

- What resolution? (1080p, 1440p, 4k)
- What refresh rate? (60hz, 144hz)
- What type of panel? (IPS, TN)
- What size screen? (You have already answered this in your question but still something to think about)
- What aspect ratio? (16:9, 21:9, etc.)
- What size of a bezel? (You mentioned this as well saying you want a thin border)
- Price?

A site that I use to check some of these is [pcpartpicker.com](http://pcpartpicker.com/parts/monitor/). You will be able to filter on all of these things directly from their site.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is some information in here that I didn't know. I also had color depth in mind. But I suppose, since you didn't mention it, I'll only have to worry about that if I'm working with image editors (such as Photoshop) and that most modern monitors will have a big enough color depth for gaming. Is that true?
I didn't really look into >1080p resolutions yet, because there isn't much content (e.g. movies) available yet. But since I do have a decent GPU I suppose a 4K monitor will bring me some kind of advantage (see more details) in modern games?

Comment: And don't forget about angle of view.

Comment: And wide / normal screen. If you play games where seeing left-right is more necessary than seeing what's on top/bottom side of screen (racing games, usual RPGs, most of shooters) then wide screen is a better option. But if you mostly play strategies, casual games then normal screens are good as well.

Comment: Also I would like to point out that it is also important to find out what video connections the video card and monitor support. (HDMI, DVI, Displayport, VGA, etc...)